# Flutter IndexedWidgetBuilder with ListView.builder with dynamic number of items?

Tags: listview, flutter, builder

Say I retrieve back some data from an API and I want to put them in a ListView.builder. I want to do lazy loading because at any time, only three items will be shown on the screen. Say the data looks something like this, where we're not guaranteed to get all the headers, and we don't know how many items are in `contents`.

```
header: HeaderOne
contents: [ItemOne, ItemTwo, ItemThree]

header: HeaderTwo
contents: [ItemOne]

header: HeaderThree // don't display this because contents is empty
contents: [] // don't display this because contents is empty

header: HeaderFour
contents: [ItemOne, ItemTwo]
```

The ListView in the UI would look like this if you scrolled through:

```
HeaderOne
ItemOne
ItemTwo
ItemThree
HeaderTwo
ItemOne
HeaderFour
ItemOne
ItemTwo
```

My `itemBuilder` property in ListView.builder() becomes something horrible. Here is some pseudocode:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index i) {
  if (i == 0 && data.hasHeaderOne) { return _buildHeaderOne(); }
  else if (i == 0 && !data.hasHeaderOne) { return _buildHeaderTwo(); }
  else if (i == 1 && data.hasHeaderOne { return _buildContents(headerOneContents[0]); }
  else if (i == (1 + data.headerOneContents.length) && data.hasHeaderOne && data.hasHeaderTwo) { return _buildContents(headerTwoContents[i+someNumberIHaveToCalculate]); }
  ...
}
```

There's definitely a better way to do this! I considered nesting ListView.builder() but not sure how that affects performance or scrolling.

The goal is to use a builder when I don't know what index each item would be at. I could calculate the total number of items (in this example, 9), but I don't see how that helps without writing convoluted if-else code.

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up doing this was to create a list of widget builders instead of widgets.
E.g. something like:

```
typedef WidgetBuilder Widget Function();

...

final itemBuilder = <WidgetBuilder>[
if (data.hasHeaderOne) () => _buildHeaderOne(),
for (item in data.headerOneContents) () => _buildContents(item),
...
];

return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: itemBuilder.length, 
  itemBuilder: (_, item) => itemBuilder[item](),
);
```